# Angular Application Unable to Access Back-end API in ASE

Tags: networking, azure

We currently have the infrastructure below designed and implemented for our solution. Our Angular application is deployed in the Front-End App Service while our .NET application is deployed in the Back-End App Service.

We have a public URL (e.g., https://publicurl.example.com) that points to our front-end App Service. Whenever I try to invoke a back-end API (e.g., https://backend.ase-01.appserviceenvironment.net/v1/api/orders), I receive an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

[image]

Upon further investigation by our infrastructure team, they found out that this is because Angular - being a client application - is invoking our back-end application directly. Since the back-end is residing inside a VNET, the Angular app could not resolve the FQDN, thus, resulting in the timeout error.

One solution that we found was to create a rule in the App GW to route all /v1/* requests to the back-end application. It works, but it partially exposes the application to the public internet which kinds of defeat the purpose of having it inside the VNET in the first place.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: What does better mean ?  I have flagged it as opinion based

Comment: Is there a way that we can have the front-end access the back-end without having to partially expose the latter to the public internet?